# Multiple forms which both go to PHP_SELF

Tags: php, forms, post

I have two forms on 1 page, how would I go about working out in PHP which forms was used?

Form 1:

```
<form name="loginform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="vuser" placeholder="Email"><br/>
    <input type="password" name="vpass" placeholder="Password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

Form 2:

```
<form name="otherform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="newu" placeholder="Email"><br/>
    <input type="password" name="newp" placeholder="Password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="New Formsss">
</form>
```

Then, my PHP code has this, but I'm not too sure how I would do it.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    //if otherform was submitted do this:
        //echo "Otherform";
    //else if loginform was submitted do this:
        //echo "Loginform";
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add two hidden fields called `action` to each one of your forms:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
```

and in the other:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="other">
```

Then, with PHP:

```
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : null;

switch($action){
    case 'other':
        //process
        break;
    case 'login':
        //process
        break;
    default:
        //action not found
        break;
}
```

Comment: Or append a GET variable to the action attribute. `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>?type=other"`

Comment: I'd prefer not to use GET variables as they can be changed easily and could break my scripts. :) Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: @KeirDavis You can change POST variables very easily w/ Firebug and Chrome developer tools. You'll still need to validate the fields, regardless of whether they are POST or GET or COOKIE etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to just use separate name for the `submit` buttons and catch which one was used;

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-a'])){
        $vuser= $_POST['vuser'];
        exec("external script $vuser");
    };

if(isset($_POST['submit-b'])){
        $newu= $_POST['newu'];
        exec("external script $newu");
    };
```

Andd the button code is;

```
<button type="submit" name="submit-a" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit-b" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

In my case I'm grabbing the vars to pass to an external script.